# How to prevent a user clicking a link to a new activity multiple times

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have noticed a bug in my android app.

I have a main screen which has 4 buttons to different activities.

When a user clicks on one of these buttons it starts a new activity.  Below is an xample of one of the buttons code which executes.

```
public void button1Clicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryMenuActivity.this,
            FoodMenuCategoriesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); // Start the new activity
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_enter,
            R.anim.activty_exit);
}
```

Now i have noticed if the user clicks on the button really fast say 5 times. it will the open 5 instances of the activity.  How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

The button click event is called in the UI thread, meaning, if you disable/hide/whatever the button in the button click callback the click events will not be triggered anymore.

Try something like the following (don't forget to enable when needed):

```
public void button1Clicked(View view) {
    // Disable the button
    view.setEnabled(false);

    Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryMenuActivity.this,
        FoodMenuCategoriesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); // Start the new activity
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_enter,
        R.anim.activty_exit);
}
```

Comment: Where would I enable it again?  In the `onResume()` method of the activity?

Comment: That depends on your app's logic. Basically, you should enabled it back when you're fine with the option that the user will click it again.

Comment: Well in this case it just opens another activity, then after some time the app returns to the original activity. Will the `onResume()` be called when the focus returns to the activity and it is reloaded up again?

Comment: Yes. I suggest reading http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. If you ask me, that's the most important thing to learn when developing to Android.

Comment: Should i disable them? or set then as not clickable?

Comment: It is up to you to decide, depending on your app's user experience. Usually, disabling them does the job since the user sees that he can't click the button and from your side, the button click events will not be fired.